# Load first json object by default - Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm hoping this is an easy question to answer...

I'm trying to create a table that loads my json, then be able to click a row and load more details that pertain to the json object. When you click a row it should load additional details at the top of the page. The row clicking part is working fine. What I'm having trouble with is loading the initial object by default.

Below is an example of what I'm referring to:

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', [ ]);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var itemsFactory = {
        itemDetails: function () {
            return $http({
                    url: "fake-phi.json",
                    method: "GET",

            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };

    return itemsFactory;

}]);

myItemsApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory',         
    function($scope, itemsFactory){
        var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.itemDetails = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        $scope.select = function (item) {
            $scope.selected = item;
        }

}]);
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/6LfAsaamCPPbe7JNdww1/

I tried adding this after $scope.select, but got an error:

```
$scope.selected = item[0];
```

How do I get the first object in my json to load by default?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your promise resolve function assign the first item of the array, as a selected value:

```
   promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        $scope.selected = data[0];
        console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: Thought I was close! I appreciate your help @ManuelObregozo!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', [ ]);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var itemsFactory = {
        itemDetails: function () {
            return $http({
                    url: "fake-phi.json",
                    method: "GET",

            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };

    return itemsFactory;

}]);

myItemsApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory',         
    function($scope, itemsFactory){
        var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.itemDetails = data;
            $scope.selected = data[0];

            console.log($scope.itemDetails);
            console.log($scope.selected);
        });

}]);
```